# Matlat function to convert cell array to text file in specific format

Tags: matlab, function

After running an algorithm, I got the output in cell array X,

```
>> X
X = 

[5x1 double]
[5x1 double]
>> celldisp(X);

X{1} =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

X{2} =

 11
 21
 31
 41
 51
 61
 71
 81
```

Please note that the dimension of the output is different. X{1} has length 5, while X{2} has length 8.
Now, I want to write this output of `celldisp(X)` to a txt file in the following format:
output.txt
1 2 3 4 5
11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81

How, can I do this? Is there a predefined function to achieve this goal OR do I need to write a custom defined function. Can someone help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
dlmwrite('output.txt',horzcat(X{:})','delimiter',' ');
```

---

For the updated question, where the length of the arrays in the cell elements is not the same, I suggest you use a loop:

```
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
for idx = 1:numel(X)
    fprintf(fid,[repmat('%d ', 1, numel(X{idx})) '\n'], X{idx});
end
fclose(fid);
```

---

Yet another edit, this time to make it a function

```
function printCellArray(filename, cellarray)

    fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
    for idx = 1:numel(cellarray)
        fprintf(fid,[repmat('%d ', 1, numel(cellarray{idx})) '\n'], cellarray{idx});
    end
    fclose(fid);

end
```

Comment: What if the dimensions of the output is not consistent. What I mean is 
X{1} =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

X{2} =

 11
 21
 31
 41
 51 61. How to handle this ? The reason being, I am getting the following error "Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
consistent."

Comment: Since the dimensions of the output are different, I suppose that I need to write a user-defined function for this. Any idea how to go about it ?

Comment: This satisfies your needs, I guess.

Comment: The output is what I desired, but there is some garbled content at the end of each line in the output file, I tried running the function without '\b' which is mentioned in the 5th line, but still the garbled content at the end of each line in the outfile persists...

Comment: I think that is caused by your text file editor. What are you using? In Matlab it looks fine here, which you can check by typing `edit output.txt`.

Comment: Hey, it got fixed now. Removing '\b' worked. Its a great function. Thanks a ton for the help. Many thanks ! Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad to be of service. If you think the answer is good, you could consider clicking the upvote symbol in addition to accepting ;)

Comment: Hey Jan, I tried to upvote your answer quite before you requesting it, but I am unable to do so as the upvoting requires minimum of 15 reputation and currently my reputation is just 12. But I will definately upvote it once I have the required reputation which wont take much long.... Thanks again and I do owe you the upvote. I will remember it :)

Comment: It was not a request.. now I feel like a rep *****. No, just kidding ;)

Comment: Hey sorry if I offended, kind of new to stack overflow, so still learning.... I truly liked your answer and it definitely deserves an upvote, which I will do since it deserves it ;)

Comment: O, I am not offended at all - it was just a joke. Have fun on Stack Overflow, I'll see you around ;)